# How to share filter between angular applications

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is probably simple question, but I cannot figure the answer.
I am developing several angular apps, I want to have one javascript file with all the filters I'm using.

Current I define the filters like this:

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp1')
app1.filter('filterCount',function() {
     return function(input) {
        ....
     }
})
```

How do I change my code to define this filter for any app that includes this file (e.g., if I want MyApp2 to use it)? Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a common module and inject it where ever you want.

```
var common = angular.module('common', []) //creates a module 'common'
common.filter('filterCount',function() {
     return function(input) {
        ....
     }
})
```

then

```
var myapp1=angular.module('myApp1',['common']);
var myapp2=angular.module('myApp2',['common']);
```

Comment: and then how do I reference filterCount within myApp1 and myApp2?

Comment: I had to change the first line by "angular.module('common', [])"